# link_to Base URL Randomly Changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm using `link_to` to create a custom link. For some reason, my url always is wrong and randomly adds `blog` to the URL. I can't figure out why. It only does this while within the partial that I am rendering (3 times on the page).

I can share any code necessary, but where the hell would it randomly grab the blog URL?

The browser renders:

`<a href="/blog?controller=quote">Select Rate</a>`

My view (using `slim`) is:

```
- for rate in loantek_rates
  - loantek_closing_costs = LoantekClosingCosts.new(rate)
  = link_to 'Select Rate', {controller: 'quote'}
```

Routes

```
#routes.rb
match "/blog" => redirect("http://blog.mywebsite.com"), path: '/blog'
resources :quotes, path: 'quote'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set paths in `link_to` tag which you can get from `rake_routes`

Ex.

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figure that out myself too! But why the hell does it pull a random route? This is very confusing and difficult to debug.