# link_to 'new' action in a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have a link at the bottom of my **show.html.erb** that `links` to the `new` action in a different controller.

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :song
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :samples
end
```

So, at the bottom of the `show` action for `songs`, I want to link to `new` for `samples`. This seems pretty easy, but I'm struggling to figure this out. I would also like to pass the id from the song to the form as `:song_id`

Answer (score 5):

Fiddy, because you're new, let me explain how this works...

---

[**Routes**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Your problem is that you don't understand the Rails routing structure - I'll hopefully explain it for you.

Rails, since it's an MVC framework, builds a series of "routes" for you. These "routes" are stored in the file available at `config/routes.rb`.

Routes, as described by the Rails documentation are as follows:

> The Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller's
>   action. It can also generate paths and URLs, avoiding the need to
>   hardcode strings in your views.

The most important thing you should consider here is the way [the routes generate *paths*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code) for you. These paths are simply Rails "helper" methods, which you can call from your views. The reason these exist is two-fold -

> 1. They provide you with a [DRY (don't repeat yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) way of accessing / manipulating data
> 2. They are constructed around *objects*, helping maintain the object-orientated nature of Rails

These will likely mean nothing to you. However, what you need to realize that if set up your routes correctly, it seriously helps your app's infrastructure immensely.

--

**Rails**

This leads us quite nicely onto appreciating the way in which Rails works

Rails is an [MVC (model view controller)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework. This might seem somewhat trivial, but in reality, it's one of the most important aspects to learn about Rails development, and here's why:

[image]

The Rails software system works by taking "requests" (user input) and then *routing* them to specific `controller#actions`. Those controllers then build `model` data from the database, and will translate that into either variables or objects, which you can use in your `view`.

The reason I mention this is that this type of development takes a lot of getting used-to, in that your program's flow is not about logic / functionality, but the accessibility of data. Therefore, when you ask about the *routes* or other parts of your app, you need to firstly remember what data you wish to show, and also how you want that data to be shown - this will give you the ability to construct & use the routes / controller actions which will get it to work properly

--

**Fix**

In terms of what you're saying, the way you'd go about achieving the result you want will be to use a [nested route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :songs do
   resources :samples #-> domain.com/songs/:song_id/samples/new
end
```

This will create a new route for you (which you can check by firing `rake routes` in your `rails c` (console). This will give you a *path* to use for your `samples#new` action:

```
#app/views/songs/show.html.erb
<%= link_to @song.name, new_song_sample_path(@song) %>
```

The above link will take you to the `samples#show` action, which you'll be able to populate with as much data as you require from the `samples` controller. The important thing to note is this action will have `params[:song_id]` available for you to either build an object from, or otherwise

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed response. I have only done one video tutorial series on Rails, and it didn't explain much of this logic, so there was a lot of memorization and guesswork going on. I just have 1 issue. The path is generating, and I see it when I use `rake routes`. However, the form generation is causing an error. At this line: `<%= form_for @sample do |f| %>` I get the following error `NoMethodError in Samples#new`. The URL looks right, and it is also passing the parameter.

Comment: Does it say what method / action it is (IE what it's trying to call, but isn't available)?

Comment: `undefined method \`samples_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000430c970>:0x0000000431d7e8`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "New Sample", new_sample_path(:song_id => @song_id) %>
```

Where `@song_id` is the variable that has that id in it.

Comment: I get an error "No route matches [POST] "/samples/new"". My routes are resources :songs and resources :samples

Comment: That should be a GET for a link_to.   Are you trying to use this in a form?

Answer (score 0):

Set paths in `link_to` tag which you can get by running `rake_routes` in terminal.

Ex

```
link_to "New song", new_sample_path(@song)
```

In the example given above `@song` is the instance variable of your current page.

You can also get some idea from here:

[link_to Base URL Randomly Changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391021/link-to-base-url-randomly-changed/25391163#25391163)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by setting paths by running rake routes in terminal.

Comment: @fiddy : in terminal as you run `rails s` to start server like that run `rake routes` you will get all paths of your app

Answer (score 0):

**Song Model:**

```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :sample, allow_destroy: true
```

**Route:**

```
resources :songs do
    resources :samples
end
```

**Song's Show file:**

```
<%= link_to "New Sample", new_song_sample_path(@song) %>
```

in url it will be:

```
/songs/:song_id/sample/new
```

Try this and let me know it works or not... I hope this helps you

Comment: It doesn't render the page. "NoMethodError in Songs#show"

Comment: @fiddy : show me your controller code & routes file